# How to assign values to the elements of a string array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am a beginner in C# and I have this code:

```
string[] student = new string[6] { "Joules", "Niki", "Hannah","Ariana", "Martin", "Loren" };
int[] mark = new int[6] { 85, 65, 70, 75, 95, 80 };
        Console.Write(student[0]);
        student[0] = mark[0].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine($"'s mark is {student[0]}");
```

I have created a string array of students and I'm trying to assign values(marks) to each of them. This code I posted is not really accurate and I need some help understanding the procedure. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

I'd avoid proceeding with that approach as it's cumbersome to deal with. instead, create a class to represent the data with the necessary fields.

Example:

```
class Student {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Mark {get; set; }
}
```

Then construct `Student` objects and populate the data which I'll leave as an exercise for you.

consult the documentation for further assistance [Objects (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/objects) as it contains some good examples which you can use.

Comment: Good answer for encouraging OP to abstract it out and leading towards good coding patterns.

Answer (score 0):

//just in case, if you trying just to print values marks to the names, respectively...

```
    string[] student = new string[6] { "Joules", "Niki", "Hannah","Ariana", "Martin", "Loren" };
    int[] mark = new int[6] { 85, 65, 70, 75, 95, 80 };    

    //student.Length or mark.Lenght, whatever
    for(int i = 0; i < student.Length ; i++ ) 
    Console.WriteLine($"{student[i]}'s mark is {mark[i]}");
```